# Magento problem in login and product view

Tags: magento-1.9

I m new in magento and I have installed magento. It's working fine.

When I installed some themes, its getting problem, like when I am login my admin panel at that time i have to type index.php between my wesite name and admin.

I want to resolve it. Even when I open any product at that time also I have to include `index.php` after that it will open like example http://ulogin.co.uk/admin this will not work but when I type http://ulogin.co.uk/index.php/admin at this time it work. Same thing happen in product open

Answer (score 1):

change your .htaccess file .. or put your fresh Magento  .htaccess file on your server root file. Hope this work ..